# How to begin a new loop from the end result of a previous loop

Tags: python, for-loop, input, while-loop, range

I have the following code in Python:

If I run the code as it is, if I input the number 9, it will run a list of numbers from 0 to 8. And each time I rerun the code, it will automatically start at 0. What additional code do I need to get this to run from the end result of the previous loop (i.e. I start with 9, and then when I go with 8 the second time, it runs the loop from 8 as that was the end result from the previous loop)?

````
while user_play == "y":

    # Ask the user how many numbers to loop through
    ask_user = input("How many numbers would you like to loop? ")


    # Loop through the numbers. (Be sure to cast the string into an integer.)
    for number in range(0,int(ask_user)):

        # Print each number in the range
        print(number)


    # Once complete, ask the user if they would like to continue
    user_play = input("Would you like to continue? ")```
````

Comment: Assign a variable as the start of the `range()`, then update that in each run

Answer (score 1):

You were close.  Just two changes are needed.

### Changes

1) Outside of the while-loop, set an initial value of *number* to zero.

2) Change the range to `range(number, number+int(ask_user))`

### Result

```
number = 0
while user_play == "y":
    ask_user = input("How many numbers would you like to loop? ")
    for number in range(number, number + int(ask_user)):
        print(number)
    user_play = input("Would you like to continue? ")
```

### How it works

The idea is that *number* always means "where you are in the looping" and that *ask_user* represents how many more steps should be run.  The *number* is starts at zero and is remembered as the steps increase.

### Variations

Depending on whether you want a step repeated, consider adding one to the *number*.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hardcoding the start of `range(0,int(ask_user))` with 0, use a variable `start` initialized at 0 and updated in each loop with the last value.

````
start = 0  # initialize at 0
while user_play == "y":

    # Ask the user how many numbers to loop through
    ask_user = input("How many numbers would you like to loop? ")


    # Loop through the numbers. (Be sure to cast the string into an integer.)
    for number in range(start, start + int(ask_user)): 

        # Print each number in the range
        print(number)
        start = number # update start


    # Once complete, ask the user if they would like to continue
    user_play = input("Would you like to continue? ")```
````